# How can I remove the first few lines of my dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code

```
# Our search function
def ndb_search(q):
    """Returns terms regarding food's foodgroup, name, NBD number, data source, and manufacturer from the USDA Food Composition Databases based on your 'q'"""
    response = requests.get("https://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search", params = {
        'api_key': key,
        'q': q,
        'offset': 0,
        'fg': "",
        'name': "",
        'ndbno': "",
        'ds': "",
        'manu': ""
    })
    # Checks if we get a HTTP status code back
    response.raise_for_status()
    # Converts out JSON format information into lists and dictionaries
    search_output = response.json()
    return search_output

ndb_search("quail eggs")
```

**This is the output I get:**
[image: Output I get]

**This is the output I want:**
[image: Output I want]

Here is the dictionary I'm trying to manipulate if it helps:

```
search_ output = {'list': {'q': 'quail eggs', 'sr': '1', 'ds': 'any', 'start': 0, 'end': 6, 'total': 6, 'group': '', 'sort': 'r', 'item': [{'offset': 0, 'group': 'Branded Food Products Database', 'name': 'EL COMPI, QUAIL EGGS, UPC: 854955002226', 'ndbno': '45362205', 'ds': 'LI', 'manu': "milly's desserts llc"}, {'offset': 1, 'group': 'Branded Food Products Database', 'name': 'BUDDHA, QUAIL EGGS IN BRINE, UPC: 761934535098', 'ndbno': '45099560', 'ds': 'LI', 'manu': 'Sung Ly International Corporation'}, {'offset': 2, 'group': 'Branded Food Products Database', 'name': 'GRAN SABANA, QUAIL EGGS, UPC: 819140010103', 'ndbno': '45169279', 'ds': 'LI', 'manu': 'L & M C Farms, Inc.'}, {'offset': 3, 'group': 'Branded Food Products Database', 'name': 'L&W, QUAIL EGGS, UPC: 024072000256', 'ndbno': '45094890', 'ds': 'LI', 'manu': 'L&W International Co.'}, {'offset': 4, 'group': 'Branded Food Products Database', 'name': 'CHAOKOH, QUAIL EGG IN BRINE, UPC: 044738074186', 'ndbno': '45094707', 'ds': 'LI', 'manu': 'Theppadung Porn Coconut Co'}, {'offset': 5, 'group': 'Dairy and Egg Products', 'name': 'Egg, quail, whole, fresh, raw', 'ndbno': '01140', 'ds': 'SR', 'manu': 'none'}]}}
```

Comment: Just get the list you want with item lookup: ``result['list']['item']``

Comment: in my answer (below) I go a (very little) bit deeper, but you probably want to use SKG s answer with ``.get()`` to avoid crashes.

Answer (score 1):

seems like you just want the 'item' so you can access by using this: `output['list']['item']`.

Answer (score 1):

```
search_output.get('list',{}).get('item',[])
```

Assuming search_output is a dictionary, this line would fetch the item list inside the list dictionary. If for some reason you do not have list or item collection inside the list, this statement would just return an empty list. This is possible based on how the API was implemented at api.nal.usda.gov.

Answer (score 0):

To get items from a dictionary, you can use item lookup (like with indexes from a list).
It works exactly the same, only accepting whatver key type you have (keys must be hashable):

```
my_dict = {'str': 1, type: lambda:None, 5: 'five'}
my_dict['str'], my_dict[type], my_dict[5]  # 1, <lambda at #???>, 'five'
```

This also works into any depth:

```
my_deep_dict = {1: {'k': [{'x': 3}]}}
my_deep_dict[1]['k'][0]['x']   # 3
```

In your case, just use `search_output['list']['item']`.